# Rendezvous vs consistent hashing

Tags: hash, distributed-computing, consistent-hashing

I read [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_hashing#Comparison_with_consistent_hashing):

> *Unlike consistent hashing, HRW (Highest Random Weight, aka Rendezvous Hashing) requires **no** precomputing or storage of tokens.*

Why?

My understanding is that:

- In consistent hashing, one hashes objects and sites independently (i.e. `h(Oi)` and `h(Sj)`) to the unit circle, and then for a given object, it finds the nearest site in the hashed space.
- In HRW (Rendezvous hashing) one hashes both objects and sites simultaneously i.e. `h(Oi, Sj)`, and then pick the highest hashed result to decide the destination site for an object.

so, if anything, it looks to me that in consistent hashing, one *could choose* to pre-compute and pre-store `h(Sj)`s but you are not **required** to do so. In other words, consistent hashing provides that flexibility whereas HRW doesn't.

Am I wrong? If so why?

Here's a reference description of HRW from the same link:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.
The fact that we can pre-compute and pre-store `h(Sj)` is rather an advantage for consistent hashing.

Wikipedia states that the advantage for Rendezvous hashing is that its conceptually simpler to understand and implement (although I dont agree personally).

And it mentions one more advantage:

> Rendezvous hashing also has the great advantage that it provides
> simple solutions to other important problems, such as distributed
> k-agreement.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation with the circle for rendezvous hashing was wrong.

**RendezVous Hashing:**
`Hash(object + Site)` : the site with the highest result (*highest random weight (HRW) hashing*) get to store the object.
If you remove a site, for every object that was on that site, redo the operation Hash(object + Site) for each site left to find the one with the highest result.

**Consistent hashing:**
Give each Site a number of Site-key(the higher the number of Site-key , the more uniform will be the repartition of objects, you generate them by : `Hash(site + number)` ). Put them on a circle.(All of this is the part that can be pre computed).
To store an object, `Hash(Object)` to get an object-key, put it on a circle and find the nearest site-key clockwise. The site that has this site-key will store the object
If you remove a site, you remove on the circle the site-keys the site had. For each object that was stored on that site , you go again clockwise on the circle to find the nearest site key.

Comment: Thanks Louis, so going back to my question: what do you think is the basis for this statement from Wikipedia? `"Unlike consistent hashing, HRW (Highest Random Weight, aka Rendezvous Hashing) requires no precomputing or storage of tokens".`?

Comment: HRW hashing require no precomputing or storage of tokens firstly because there are no token(site-keys) with HRW and secondly, to find where you will store the object , you have to hash(object+site) (to find the highest random weight). Since you don't know in advance what object you will want to store , you can't precompute the hash.
However, this is not a big disadvantage since you need to do one hash (like with Consistent hashing) to know where to store an object.

Comment: ok thanks, I mention this because the way this is worded in Wikipedia is as if it's a _good_ thing that HRW requires no pre-computing / storage of tokens, but you seem to agree with me that that **none** of them require the pre-computing of those hashes, and thus, if anything, consistent hashing offers the **flexibility** to pre-compute / store those hashes. Right?